# Existen algún problema entre PHP y Mysql con procedimientos almacenados?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Buenas el dia de ayer estaba trabajando con unos procedimientos almacenados en PHP y mostrando los resultados en una tabla

el problema consistía en que al ejecutar dos procedimientos almacenados solo devolvía el primer resultado  y el segundo no .

```html
$pfechainicial = $_POST['txt_fecfaincial'];
$pfechafinal = $_POST['txt_fechafin'];
$pcanal = $_POST['cbo_canal'];
$pcia = $_POST['cbo_companias'];
$psucursal = $_POST['cbo_sucursales'];

$query = "call`rep_dist_real_cobertura_distribucion`('$psucursal','$pcia','$pcanal','$pfechainicial','$pfechafinal');";
$resp = obtenerRegistros($query);
print_r($resp);
  
$query2 = "call `rep_dist_distribucion`('$psucursal','$pcia','$pcanal','$pfechainicial', '$pfechafinal');";
$resp2 = obtenerRegistros($query2);
print_r($resp2);
```

Solo devuelve el valor de el procedimiento que ejecuto primero  si los cambio de lugar el otro funciona correctamente

aqui les muestro la funcion obtener registros y la conexion

```html
  try {
       $conexion = new mysqli($server, $user, $pswd ,
                              $database, $port);
       if($conexion->connect_errno){
            //die();
            die($conexion->connect_error);
       }
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "error en conexion";
          exit;
        }
        

        // ---------------------obtener Registros---------------------------------------
           function obtenerRegistros($sqlstr, &$conexion = null){
                if(!$conexion) global $conexion;
                $result = $conexion->query($sqlstr);
                $resultArray = array();
                foreach($result as $registro){
                    $resultArray[] = $registro;
                }
                return $resultArray;
           }
```

Comment: Debes cerrar la conexión para que quede disponible para volver a llamarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba con cerrar la primera conexión para luego abrir la segunda